# Cannot build in Visual studio with remote linux machine after upgrade to VS2022, "ClCompile" target is failing

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio, gcc, gdb

I have a linux project that I had not worked on in a while. It is a remote linux build from Visual studio in Windows, following the workflow [in this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/download-install-and-setup-the-linux-development-workload?view=msvc-170).

I created the project in VS2019, worked on it on and off for a while, and then had not touched it for a few months. Recently I upgraded to VS2022, and tried to work on it again. Now when I try to build I'm hit with the following error, which does not tell me anything particularly useful. It's relating to the build target "ClCompile", but the error offers me little idea about whats wrong or what I can do about it (full log below):

```
Target ClCompile:
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)

{ many lines omitted, see below for complete log }

Done building target "ClCompile" in project "{PROJECT}.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "{PROJECT}.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
```

I have done the following:

- Updated GCC, GDB, GDBServer
- Rebooted the machine
- Created an empty project with "hello world" printed to output - builds and runs fine

Windows Machine software versions:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.3.6
- Windows 10 version 22H2

Linux machine software versions:

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- GCC 9.4.0
- GDB 10.2

If I turn on "diagnostic" level build logging, I can see all of the output from the target "ClCompile" before it fails:

```
Target "ClCompile" in file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets":
  Using "MultiMakeCl" task from assembly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Microsoft.Build.Linux.Tasks.dll".
  Task "MultiMakeCl"
    Task Parameter:RemoteIntermediateDir=/home/{user}/{ProjectName}/vsLinux/{ProjectName}/obj/x64/Tests
    Task Parameter:IntermediateDir=C:\{user}\{ProjectName}\LinuxSolution\obj\x64\Tests\
    Task Parameter:RemoteProjectDir=/home/{user}/{ProjectName}/vsLinux/{ProjectName}/LinuxSolution/
    Task Parameter:ProjectDir=C:\{user}\{ProjectName}\LinuxSolution\
    Task Parameter:RemoteOutputDir=/home/{user}/{ProjectName}/vsLinux/{ProjectName}/bin/x64/Tests
    Task Parameter:RemoteTarget=-1151915053;192.168.0.12 (username=, port=22, authentication=Password)
    Task Parameter:
        ImportedProjects=
            C:\dev\HotLink\LinuxSolution\HotLink.vcxproj
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Xaml.targets
            C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\17.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets
    Task Parameter:
        Sources=
{ very long list of each source file and all project settings related to them }

Task Parameter:OutputDir=C:\dev\{ProjectName}\LinuxSolution\bin\x64\Tests\
    Task Parameter:EnableASAN=False
    Task Parameter:IncludePath=C:\dev\{ProjectName}\LinuxSolution\..\thirdParty\;C:\dev\{ProjectName}\LinuxSolution\..\src\;;;

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at Microsoft.Build.Linux.Tasks.MultiMakeCl.PopulateTaskFromSourceItem(ITaskItem source, MakeClCommandLine schedulingTask, PropertyInfo[] propertyInfo)
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at Microsoft.Build.Linux.Tasks.MultiMakeCl.ExecuteTool()
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Application Type\Linux\1.0\Linux.targets(399,5): error :    at Microsoft.Build.Linux.Tasks.RemoteToolTask.Execute()
Done building target "ClCompile" in project "{PROJECT}.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Done building project "{PROJECT}.vcxproj" -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
```

Has anyone else experienced this? Does anyone know what else I can try?

Comment: `had not touched it for a few months` Will there be the error when building again in VS2019? Try starting over to create the project in VS2022.